# Finding the minimum number (named as "n") from the function of e

Tags: c

good day, I am making a program that is using the e function:

```
e(n) = 1 + (1/1!) + (1/2!)+ ... + (1/n!)
```

with this function of C:

```
double e(double x, double x2){
    double sum, kf;
    int i, m, n;    
    // printf("Please input the number of x: ");
    // scanf("%lf", &x);    
    
    sum = 0.0;
    
    for (i=1; i<=x; i++){
        kf=1.0;
        for (m=1; m<=i; m++) {
            kf*=1.0/m;
        }
        sum+=kf;
    }
return printf("e=%lf\n", 1+sum);
}
```

well, it was the e function. now, I want to find the minimum number n that makes:

> |e(n) - e(n+1)| < x
>
> > (absolute value of e(n) - e(n+1) is smaller than x

where x is a long float that users input, will be 0.1, 0.001, 0.0001,...

Any answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you delete the actual question if you "really need someone to help"?

Answer (score 1):

Using algebra and the `e` function definition, `|e(n) - e(n+1)| < x` can be simplified to `(1/n!) < x`, which can be expanded to `(1/1) * (1/2) * (1/3) * ... * (1/n) < x`.

```
int minN(double x) {
    double sum = 1;
    int n;
    for(n = 0; sum >= x; n++) {
       sum *= 1/(n+1);
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: return i? how do I print this on the main function?
    printf("%d", i);
isn't working if I don't declare it.. if I do, i will be a mysterious integer :o

Comment: you need to invoke my `minN` function like this: `printf("%d",minN(x));`

Comment: oh yeah, i forgot about that one. I invoked the function before the printf line x_x

Comment: you could also do `int n = minN(x); printf("%d",n);`

Comment: it works but I still don't know, whatever the number is, the answer is always 2..

Comment: Leaving aside the glaring coding error, those two expressions are obviously not equivalent; look at n=1.